# is there any way to popup an alert message using variables as soon as window opens?

Tags: javascript, html

Create an object called person with name = Ali, age = 30. Then, access the object to
alert("Ali is 30"). Add the following property and value to the person object: country:
Norway. Display all the properties in object (assume at least 2 more properties with
values assigned).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly..

```js
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if ('complete' === document.readyState) {
    let person = {
      name: "Ali",
      age: 30
    }
    alert(person.name + " is " + person.age);
    person.someOtherProperty = "someOtherValue";
    person.anotherProperty = "anotherValue";
    console.log(person);
  }
};
```